# Does F# have a AND in types or a type hierarchy with parent Number?

Tags: f#, types, ml

I want to define a list of ints and floats, where [1,2.0] should be a valid construction.

Does F# have a AND in types or a type hierarchy with int and floats derived from Number for example?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `[1, 2.0]` *is* valid F# but it is a list with one element that is a pair containing an `int` and a `float`.

Answer (score 5):

No, F# / .NET does not have a numeric tower like Python, or a common `Number` base type like Java.

Perhaps you could define a discriminant union like so for your purposes:

```
type Number =
    | Float of float
    | Int of int

let x = [Float(3.2); Int(2)] //val x : Number list = [Float 3.2; Int 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

F# does not have a numerical tower like Lisp/Scheme.

The only kind of union type supported is a disjoint union which must include a tag. You could write:

```
type Num = Int of int | Float of float

[Int 1; Float 2.0]
```

The value above has type `Num list`. To consume the elements, you would use pattern matching:

```
match num with
| Int x -> printf "%i" x
| Float x -> printf "%f" x
```